# How to posticipate schema inference of a DF based on a field's value?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a field `my_structure` that changes structure based on the value of `my_type`, so for example

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|             my_type|        my_structure|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   a|           [1, 2, 3]|
|                   a|           [4, 5, 6]|
|                   b|                null|
|                   c|               ['Z']|
|                   c|               ['X']|
```

`my_structure`'s structure changes according to `my_type`'s value: with `a` is a `struct` with 3 elements, with `b` is `null` and with `c` a struct with only one string value.

How to have 3 different dataframes each of them with its specific structure?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the method [`toJSON()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toJSON.html) comes handy to defer the schema inferring after filtered the DF based on the values of interest:

```
df.cache()

df.filter("my_type = 'a'").toJSON()
df_a = spark.read.json(df)

df.filter("my_type = 'b'").toJSON()
df_b = spark.read.json(df)

df.filter("my_type = 'c'").toJSON()
df_c = spark.read.json(df)

df.unpersist()
```

I'm cached the source `df` as it is being called 3 times in this case, so to improve performance.

But in this way `df_a`, `df_b` and `df_c` have 3 different structures inferred at "runtime" based on the value assumed by `my_type`